# Nitro R/C buggy starts then engine quits

Tags: small-engine, rc-vehicle

I have a nitro remote-controlled nb16 buggy.

When I put the glowstarter in the engine and start the engine and remove the glowstarter everything runs fine.

However, once I press the accelerator on the remote controller the buggy gives a little rev and the engine quits.

How do you fix this ?

Comment: Open the main needle a bit. Sounds like it's not getting enough gas.

Comment: Will the engine on the buggy continue to idle if you don't touch the throttle? Or does it quit after some time?

Comment: It continues to idle but then it quits when I press the accelerator on the remote

Comment: It's okay I fixed it. The engine was too rich and so was getting to much gas so I had to lean out the high speed needle :)